# Mod Syntax in Clojure

Tags: clojure, modulus

How do I write modulus syntax in programming language clojure?

For example the symbols money %= money_value.

Comment: convert this into clojure "money %= money_value"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two functions in Clojure you might want to try: [`mod`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/mod) and [`rem`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/rem). They work the same for positive numbers, but differently for negative numbers. Here's an example from the docs:

```
(mod -10 3) ; => 2
(rem -10 3) ; => -1
```

**Update:**

If you really want to convert your code to Clojure, you need to realize that an idiomatic Clojure solution probably won't look anything like your JavaScript solution. Here's a nice solution that I think does roughly what you want:

```
(defn change [amount]
  (zipmap [:quarters :dimes :nickels :pennies]
    (reduce (fn [acc x]
              (let [amt (peek acc)]
                (conj (pop acc)
                      (quot amt x)
                      (rem amt x))))
            [amount] [25 10 5])))

(change 142)
; => {:pennies 2, :nickels 1, :dimes 1, :quarters 5}
```

You can look up any of the functions you don't recognize on [ClojureDocs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/). If you just don't understand the style, then you probably need some more experience programming with [higher-order functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). I think [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) is a good place to start.

Comment: How about this in clojure...

var change = function (amount) {
    var QUARTER_VALUE = 25, DIME_VALUE = 10, NICKEL_VALUE = 5;

    var quarters = Math.floor(amount / QUARTER_VALUE);
    amount %= QUARTER_VALUE;
    var dimes = Math.floor(amount / DIME_VALUE);

Comment: @user1585646 that's not clojure?

Comment: I know but i want to convert it to clojure.

Comment: That's a different question. Also, I think you're missing code. As it stands, I'm not sure that makes any sense.

Comment: @user1585646 - There you go, now you have a Clojure version! (I've updated my answer.)